# Vim Turn off syntax highlight for some elements

Tags: vim, highlighting, code-folding

I'm trying to redefine the default syntax highlight for the `Folded` element so that it does not show an undesirable background color like the one on the right:

[image]

What I want is something like `:highlight Folded ctermbg=` or `:highlight Folded unset ctermbg`. But when I do that, vim says

> E417: missing argument: ctermbg=

Setting the background color to `Black` does not work. The resulting "black" is different from the real black background.

Is there a way I can remove such background?

Comment: try `ctermbg=NONE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ctermbg=NONE` this should disable the background color.